# Keep a button disabled every time the form loads

Tags: c#

I have two forms (`Form1` and `Form2`).

`Form1` has some other controls which are saved to the database after all the fields are filled. It also has a DELETE button where you can delete the searched information from the database and it has the "Available Rooms" button, which when clicked will load `Form2`.

`Form2` has a number of buttons (unoccupied rooms) which I can select from. Now, my problem is how to keep that selected button (eg.: 101) on `Form2` disabled when I click on "Available rooms" for a second time, or any other day and also keep any other selected button (eg.: 102) disabled when `Form2` loads the next time, etc.

To make it clear, the only time I want the disabled button on `Form2` be active, is when I click on the DELETE button on Form1. But, this I cad do it.

Comment: show your code .... don't ask question.like this

Comment: Use a bool with class scope. condition your event on the bool being true, then set it to flase when you want to do operations without triggering the event

Comment: Use config, ini, xml files... at application startup read from those files

Comment: Anyone trying to help you is pretty much guessing. It would help a lot if you shared your code so we had a bettr idea of what you needed

Comment: Like shannon's comment, the files should have each room, followed by a boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Form load event - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx

When you load Form 2, read the database. You already know the condition when the button for the room needs to be disabled. For example, for simplicity let's assume that you can read a column of the database into a c# boolean(say unAvailable) and based on that you can make a decision whether the room is available. So on your form 2 load (handle Form load event) there needs to be a condition like -

```
Form_Load(System.Object sender, 
System.EventArgs e)
{
    roomButton.Enabled = unAvailable;
}
```

So based on the value of field unAvailabled the roomButton is enabled or disabled.

Comment: can I get the complete code please, if you don't mind? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks so much. Even though, couldn't figure it out using the boolean as you suggested,I relied on the rest of your answer to get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you are starting the new Form2, save the form variable and use it to access its values. You should be able to access the `button.Enabled` property of your button on Form2.

This is what your code on Form1

```
Form2 secondForm;

private void button_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (secondForm != null)
    {
        secondForm.yourButton.Enabled = true;
    }
    // Any other code you want to handle
}
private void Form2_Closing (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    secondForm = null;
}
```

And this is what you should do everytime you open/show Form2:

```
secondForm = new Form2();
secondForm.Show();
secondForm.Closing += new System.EventHandler(Form2_Closing);
```

EDIT: Thanks Hans Passant! Forgot that. You should also set the value of `secondForm` to null if the form is closed. Edited the code above.

Comment: Half-way there.  Subscribe the FormClosed event and set *secondForm* back to null.

Comment: @IanH,  thanks for your input and as I'm trying to replicate it, can you help me on how to get the "Form2_Closing" event on Form1?

Comment: @Moni The code I supplied should work just on Form1. Have the `Form2_Closing` on the Form1 and add it to the second form as I showed above. Remember to mark it as an answer if it fulfills your needs.

Comment: @IanH, which exactly Form1 do you refer to? Because I find it hard("impossible") to raise Form2_Closing event on Form1 as per your code above. Your help please.

Comment: @Moni You don't have to manually raise it, just add the event handler of `Form2_Closing` (which is located on form1) to the second forms `Closing` event like this: `secondForm.Closing += new System.EventHandler(Form2_Closing);`

Answer (score 0):

I must say thank you for all your comments and answers above. Going through them, my mind was opened to think differently particularly using the Form_Load event  on Form2 and when did, it worked like a charm!!!!.

All I did on the Form2_Load event was to read the Apartment_No column(as per one contributor suggested) in the database, and use each of the values to disable the corresponding button using the switch... case.

Here is the code below:

```
     private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-J6KRI77\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = SELLnBUY; Integrated Security = true";
        string cmdstr = "SELECT Apartment_No FROM Apartment";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader r = com.ExecuteReader();


        while (r.Read())
        {
          int room = int.Parse(r["Apartment_No"].ToString());

            switch(room)
            {
                case 101:               
                        button1.Enabled = false;
                        break;                       
                case 102:                       
                        button2.Enabled = false;
                        break;
                    case 103:
                        button3.Enabled = false;
                        break;
                case 104:
                        button4.Enabled = false;
                        break;

            }
        }
        con.Close();
```